# javascript regular expression to track page title

Tags: javascript

I have written a below code to return user friendly  Page title
    but the problem is that every time the page load(with both url) page  title " Web Page 1" return. Below I have given 2 url

```
  function(){
        var pageTitle = document.title;
             try{
               if(/\/xyx\-abc\- result(\/|)$/i.test(location.pathname)){    
                   pageTitle = "Web Page 1";
               } 
             else if(/\/xyx\-abc\-result\/pqr\-mno\-efg\-lmn(\/|)$/i.test(location.pathname))                                                           
              { 
                   pageTitle = "Web Page 2";
              }

          } catch(err){}
             return pageTitle;
   }
```

page url   1)   `http://sports.com/xyz-abc-result`

Page Url   2)   `http://sports.com/xyz-abc-result/pqr-mno-efg-lmn`

Can anybody suggest what changes needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.split()` , `.slice()`

```
var loc = location.href.split("-").slice(-1)[0];
document.title = loc === "result" 
                 ? "Web Page 1" 
                 : loc === "lmn" 
                   ? "Web Page 2" : document.title;
```

Comment: thnx guest271314 & Ivar

Comment: @Sameer Does `js` at one of the solutions provided resolve Question ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws in your regex. First there is a space in the first one, and secondly you search for xyx while your paths have xyz

If I use this code it works the way it should:

```
var pageTitle = document.title;
var pathname = "/xyz-abc-result/pqr-mno-efg-lmn";
try {
    if (/\/xyz\-abc\-result(\/|)$/i.test(pathname)) {
        alert("Web Page 1");
    } else if (/\/xyz\-abc\-result\/pqr\-mno\-efg\-lmn(\/|)$/i.test(pathname)) {
        alert("Web Page 2");
    }
} catch (err) {}
return pageTitle;
```

If you run it like this, it will prompt "Web Page 2". If you change the pathname to `http://sports.com/xyz-abc-result` it will prompt "Web Page 1"